# Collapsible group words

Tags: gr.group-theory, co.combinatorics

> What is the length $f(n)$ of the shortest nontrivial group word $w_n$ in $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ that collapses to $1$ when we substitute $x_i=1$ for any $i$?

For example, $f(2)=4$, with the commutator $[x_1,x_2]=x_1 x_2 x_1^{-1} x_2^{-1}$ attaining the bound.

For any $m,n \ge 1$, the construction $w_{m+n}(\vec{x},\vec{y}):=[w_m(\vec{x}),w_n(\vec{y})]$ shows that $f(m+n) \le 2 f(m) + 2 f(n)$.

Is $f(1),f(2),\ldots$ the same as sequence [A073121](http://oeis.org/A073121):
$$ 1,4,10,16,28,40,52,64,88,112,136,\ldots ?$$

**Motivation:** Beating the iterated commutator construction would improve the best known bounds in [size of the smallest group not satisfying an identity](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15022/size-of-the-smallest-group-not-satisfying-an-identity/15065#15065).

Comment: Erik Demaine, in his paper "Puzzles, Art, and Magic with Algorithms" hints at a preprint "Picture-hanging puzzles" which might have a better (?) solution.  A google search doesn't turn up the preprint. 

Here is another link, giving your solution: 
http://www.mathpuzzle.com/hangingpicture.htm

Comment: A question.  Can one prove that such a word w_n must lie in the nth stage of the lower central series of the free group?  Ten minutes of thinking yielded neither a proof nor a counterexample.

Comment: Andy: Proposition 2 of Johnson's "Towards a characterization of smooth braids" gives a positive answer to your question.  I have not yet understood his proof.  

Answer (score 21, accepted):

See the paper "Brunnian links" by Gartside and Greenwood, published in Fundamenta Mathematicae.  Theorems 8 and 7 imply that iterated commutators are optimal and the sequence you suggest gives the minimal length.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this is https://oeis.org/A073121

Answer (score 19):

In an unpublished manuscript "Picture-Hanging Puzzles" by Erik D. Demaine, Martin L. Demaine, Yair N. Minsky, and Joseph S. B. Mitchell, we prove the $O(n^2)$ upper bound that comes from iterated commutator with a balanced split, same as sequence A073121.  (Indeed, the manuscript cites that sequence.)  We conjecture that there's an $\Omega(n^2)$ lower bound (and indeed that A073121 is exactly tight), but haven't proved it.  If you come up with a proof, it might breath some life into that manuscript and we could consider joining forces.

Comment: The preprint is here: http://arxiv.org/abs/1203.3602