# Borromean braids

Tags: gr.group-theory, braid-groups

Consider the Kernel $K_n$ of the natural group homomorphism from the $n$-th [braid group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braid_group) to the symmetric group. Then one can delete the $m$-th braid. This is a well defined homomorphism $d_m:K_n\rightarrow K_{n-1}$. So is there for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$ a braid $1\neq b\in K_n$ with $d_m(b)=0$ for all $m$.

This is clearly true for $n=2$, as $K_1$ is trivial and it is also true for $n=2$ (The "standard" braid does the job). What about higher $n$. Is there a nice construction, that works for every $n$ ?

Comment: Jim's offered a fine answer, also the following question may also be relevant: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/15316/collapsible-group-words

Comment: In fact, these form a group consisting of all pseudo-Anosov elements, as proved by Kim Whittlesey in her thesis:
http://www.msp.warwick.ac.uk/gt/2000/04/p010.xhtml

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Certain elements in the $n-1$st term of the lower central series of the pure braid group should work. 
The pure braid group is generated by generators $\beta_{i,j}$ where the $i$th strand pushes a finger over the intervening strands and hooks with the $j$th strand.
Then, when $n=3$, the commutator $[\beta_{1,2},\beta_{1,3}]$ is Brunnian in in your sense.   For $n=4$ you can consider $[\beta_{1,2},[\beta_{1,3},\beta_{1,4}]]$, etc. You need to make sure your commutator includes every $\beta_{1,k}$.

Something like $[\sigma_1^2,[\sigma_2^2,\sigma_3^2]]$ would also work.

The reason this works is that deleting a strand from the braid kills at least one generator involved in the iterated commutator, so that it collapses to $1$. That's why you need to include a generator $\beta_{i,j}$ that involves each strand.

(This has been edited to remove inaccuracies of previous versions.)

Comment: Either I am misunderstanding something or for $n=3$ the element $[\sigma_1,\sigma_2]$ does not lie in the Kernel $K_n$. Its image is $[(1,2),(2,3)]=(1,2,3)\in \Sigma_3$.

Comment: Sorry, you should take pure braid generators to make this work! I will edit this to reflect that.

Answer (score 7):

Ted Stanford has a paper on this topic, *Brunnian braids and some of their generalizations* (arXiv:[math/9907072](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9907072)), giving a set of generators for the kernel.