# Shortest almost trivial element of free group

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, free-groups

Let $F_n$ be the free group with $n$ generators $\gamma_1,\dots,\gamma_n$.
Consider the homomorphisms $h_i\colon F_n\to F_{n-1}$ defined by adding the relation $\gamma_i=1$ in $F_n$.

> What is the least word norm of a nontrivial element $\gamma\in F_n$ such that $h_i(\gamma)=1$ for each $i$?

Comment: One obvious candidate is a nested commutator $[ [\cdots [ [\gamma_1, \gamma_2], \gamma_3], \cdots], \gamma_n ]$.

Comment: @SamHopkins but is it shortest?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2178878/431882

Comment: $[[\gamma_1,\gamma_2],[\gamma_3,\gamma_4]]$ has length 16, hence shorter than $[[[\gamma_1,\gamma_2],\gamma_3],\gamma_4]$ of length 22. (More generally a quadratic bound follows, much better than the exponential size nested commutator, as observed in the PS-linked paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1203.3602)

Comment: See the link above for a copy of this question, previously answered. The question is *not* open, but this does not seem to be very well-known. The exact minimum (which is roughly quadratic in $n$) is determined in the paper https://eudml.org/doc/282667 "Brunnian links" by Gartside and Greenwood. This question also appeared recently again at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4845211/morphism-on-the-commutator-subgroup-of-the-free-group-picture-hanging-puzzle

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Repeating from the comments section:

This (natural and beautiful) question was previously asked and answered on this site. See [Collapsible group words](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15316/collapsible-group-words). It also appeared recently [on math.se](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4845211/morphism-on-the-commutator-subgroup-of-the-free-group-picture-hanging-puzzle).

The question is **not** open, but this does not seem to be well-known. The exact minimum (which is roughly quadratic in $n$), as well as the number and structure of all minimizing elements, was determined in the remarkable paper "[Brunnian links](https://eudml.org/doc/282667)" by Gartside and Greenwood. A minimizing element is indeed given by iterated commutators of the generators.

I am not sure why this paper was overlooked by the [Demaine et al. survey](https://arxiv.org/abs/1203.3602), given the date that paper appeared and the answers in the linked MO question.

Comment: So, is this https://oeis.org/A073121 ?

Comment: @YCor Yes it is.

Comment: Precisely, by induction, given $n\ge 2$, write $m=\lceil n/2\rceil$, and let $c_m$, $c_{n-m}$ be minimizing words on $m$ and $n-m\in\{m,m-1\}$ variables. Then $c_n(x_1,\dots,x_n)=[c_m(x_1,\dots,x_m),c_{n-m}(x_{m+1},\dots,x_n)]$ is minimizing, with $c_1(x_1)=x_1$. So $c_2(x,y)=[x,y]$, $c_3(x,y,z)=[[x,y],z]$, $c_4(\dots)=[[x,y],[z,w]]$, $c_5(\dots)=[[[x,y],z],[w,t]]$, etc., yields a minimizing sequence.